# Random array value after return c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization

My problem is I don't know what happens with data that I put into my arrays and how to make them stay in array. While debugging it is clear that arr gets initialized with zeros and arr2 with {1,2,3}. Functions however return some random values.. can someone help me to point out what it should be like?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class A
{
private:
    double arr[5];
public:
    A() 
    {
    std::fill( arr, arr + 5, 0.0 );
    };
    ~A() {};
    void setArr( double arrx[] ) 
    {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
      arr[i] = arrx[i];
    }
    double* getArr(void) { return arr;}
};

int* probe()
{
    int arr2[3] = {1,2,3};
    return arr2;
}
int main()
{
    A ob1;
    double rr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    ob1.setArr(rr);
    std::cout << ob1.getArr() << std::endl;
    std::cout << probe() << std::endl;
    system("Pause");
}
```

EDIT:
Now thanks to you i realize I have to loop the get** function to obtain all values. But how can I loop it if my planned usage is to write it like you see below into some file?

```
pF = fopen ("myfile.csv","a");
if (NULL != pF) 
{
   char outp[1000];
   sprintf_s(outp, 1000, "%6d,\n", ob1.getArr());
   fputs(outp, pF);
   fclose(pF);
}
```

Comment: Tried to find your problems using a debugger already?

Comment: What do you think `std::cout << ob1.getArr() << std::endl ;` does ?

Comment: Yes. Untill it is in function or constructor it gets initialized well, but after going back to main is not. Seems like I write data into some local variable which looses scope, but how to do it then properly??

Comment: @P0W in that function I want to return the whole content of array, I think it passes the &arr[0] and in such manner returns that all. Is that correct?

Comment: you cannot print whole array with std::cout  it will just print the address of returned array

Comment: `probe` returns the address of a local variable...

Comment: Why do you `#include <vector>` if you don't use them? I guess you wouldn't have the problems if you would use vectors instead of arrays.

Comment: @tgmaht i tried it working with vectors, works but i need to use arrays

Comment: @beginh: "I need to use arrays" - then use `std::array` (or your own class containing an array, if you're stuck in the past). You can't return a regular array from a function, but you can return class types like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
std::cout << ob1.getArr() << std::endl;
std::cout << probe() << std::endl;
```

You are actually printing the pointers (address), not the values which are `double` or `int`. You need to loop through all the elements of the array to print them.

As pointed out by P0W that accessing element of `probe()` has undefined behaviour, in that case you must make sure that the array should be valid. One quick solution is that declare the array static in the function.

As you want to write the value in the file

```
pF = fopen ("myfile.csv","a");
if (NULL != pF) 
{
   char outp[1000];
   int i;
   int retsofar=0;

   for(i=0;i<5;++i)
       retsofar+=sprintf_s(outp+retsofar, 1000-retsofar, "%6d,\n", ob1.getArr()[i]);

   fputs(outp, pF);
   fclose(pF);
}
```

Comment: No for `probe()` simply iterating on elements of returned pointer, will be a UB

Comment: I understand what you are saying but cannot think out of how to implement in my case, maybe for sake to keep it clear i will update my post above..

Comment: @dbasic and P0W Updated, please have a look on that situation

Comment: Thank you, now i realized that ob1 contains the inserted values but I had jus tproblems to print them correctly. I was mistaken because when I hove over ob1 with cursor during debug I don't see values, just some number (which is actually a pointer to those values)

Answer (score 0):

1. you are trying to print the addresses of arrays returned by `ob1.getArr()` and `probe()` methods. Every time you are getting different addresses. If you want to print array, use loop.
2. In probe(), you are creating an array on stack and simply returning it's pointer. It is not safe. When it goes out of scope, its values can be overwritten and you may get un expected behaviour. So create that array on heap.